# zookeeper jar in $HOME/.ivy2/jars for java application

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-zookeeper

My application is failing because of the following issue :

```
Source '/.../.ivy2/jars/org.apache.zookeeper_zookeeper-3.4.6.jar' does not exist
```

But I see, there exists a jar in that folder with "tests" suffix - org.apache.zookeeper_zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar

If I remove -tests from the name manually, the application runs fine.

I need to understand how can I place the jar my application is expecting in .ivy folder through my program/dependency.

Also, when are the all jars loaded in .ivy/jars folder, is it during the build?

I am using java with maven.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.6</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

add this to your maven dependencies also the `org.apache.zookeeper_zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar` is for the test environment.